# How to make links that get blocked by adblock

Tags: html, adblock

I'd like to know how I can have a link to an external page that is not visible to adblock users.

I have tried many things including giving it a div id="ad", and iframes. Is there maybe something I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example. I display the GoogleAdsense logo outside of the screen. If the image has no height it was blocked -> there is a AdBlocker

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AdBlock Detector</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         //Is there a AdBlocker?
         function isAdBlocker(){
             var a = document.getElementById("adTest");
             return a.offsetHeight==0;
         }

         //Hide all Links tagged with 'add="true"'
         function protectLinks(){
             if(isAdBlocker()){
                  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                  for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
                       if(links[i].getAttribute("ad"))
                            links[i].style.display="none";
             }
         }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="protectLinks()">

You can't see this link with enabled AdBlocker
<a ad="true" href="http://google.de">Link to Google</a>

<img id="adTest" style="position:absolute; left:-5000px" src="https://www.google.com/images/logos/adsense_logo_sm.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Insert the little Script and the "adTest" `div` in your Blog and give all links you want to protect a `ad="true"` attribute.

(And don't forgett to call the `protectLinks()` function after page is loaded.)

Comment: I'm not actually running ads that are being blocked. I was just hoping for a simple html style markup that might cause adblock to flag a set of code to be hidden. I can understand the part there with the div markups, but anything above that has me confused,

Comment: Any ads I would use look like this: [code]<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=178 height=46 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=http://adserver.enteradnetworkhere.com/adshow.php?adzone=233603></iframe> Although none are currently active, I can turn them on if needed for this to work.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. Look at it and be happy :-)

Comment: Did you have this tested and working or am I just failing at setting it up right?

Comment: I tested it with Firefox 21.0 for Ubuntu

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors (in the error console / log) ?

Comment: Blogger forces me to add closing tags before it lets me save it. I don't know if that is what is breaking the code or not. It makes me add a > at the end of <links.length and then it makes me do a </links.length> and it also makes me do a /> after the google img and then it lets me save it.

Comment: hm yea i think that is the reason
you could try to put the javascript in a extra file and include it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="[url to the script file]">`